# LINQ Get Properties of Class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How can I get list of properties of a object/class using linq??

```
public class Person  { 
public string Name   { get; set; } 
public string Age    { get; set; } 
public string Gender { get; set; } 
}
```

I want to {"Name","Age","Gender"}.

Comment: You might be thinking of reflection. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a previous commenter mentioned, reflection is the tool you should use to acquire this information.

Following is a small example program that will retrieve and display the property names from a hypthetical "Person" class:

```
System.Type type = typeof(Person);
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in properties)
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use reflection.
Here's a function that I have used on many projects.

```
private List<MemberInfo> GetMembers(Type objectType, MemberTypes memberType)
{
    List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();

    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(objectType);
    foreach (Type t in asm.GetExportedTypes().Where((Type testType) => object.ReferenceEquals(testType, objectType))) {
        foreach (MemberInfo mi in t.GetMembers().Where((MemberInfo member) => member.MemberType == memberType)) {
            switch (memberType) {
                case MemberTypes.Property:
                    members.Add(mi);
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.Method:
                    bool isValid = true;

                    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties()) {
                        if ((pi.CanWrite && pi.GetSetMethod().Name == mi.Name) || (pi.CanRead && pi.GetGetMethod().Name == mi.Name)) {
                            isValid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    if (isValid)
                        members.Add(mi);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return members.OrderBy((MemberInfo mi) => mi.Name).ToList();
}
```

To call it, you can use, for example:

```
var properties = GetMembers(typeof(myObject), MemberTypes.Property)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is MemberTypes.Property? Where can I have this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: The `MemberTypes` enumeration is available in the `System.Reflection` namespace.
To use it, simply add `Imports System.Reflection` at the begining of your code, before any `Class` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(Person).GetProperty("Name")
```

You can get the individual properties using Reflection. For more details read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial).